# When I try to log in with Google or Facebook, it tries to create a new account

Tags: support, jobs

I have a StackExchange account (obviously) that Google Chrome automatically logs me into when I go to stackoverflow.com. When I search my log in accounts in my settings, it says I have my Facebook and Gmail account linked up. However, when I try to log into those accounts from Careers 2.0 to create a "link" between my StackExchange and Careers account using my Gmail or Facebook, it just creates a new account with no reputation. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: I am having same problem, I have my PC logged into StackOverflow using MyOpenId with 6k reputation points. When I try and login on another PC, the MyOpenId endpoint is not found and the google login has lost all my history? Did you resolve this?

Comment: This appears to be by design, a Careers developer will have to merge the accounts.

Comment: It seems to be working now. The only thing I did was make sure all my StackExchange windows were closed, then deleted cookies and history. Either they fixed it or cookies did.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that today when I clicked to comment on this post, it said I needed an account and only had options to "sign up". I made a new tab and tried the "sign up" option and at first it started an account with no reputation, then seemed to magically find my old stackexchange account and now I have 31 reputation. No clue why that worked.

Comment: Cheers, no idea too but glad all is working now.

Comment: Hm, but my careers account is now disabled and I can't even find the information I entered :(

Comment: Email the careers team then.